# How can I iterate with .each on this code?

Tags: jquery

Still learning and need some help please.

This code example checks the validity of a url:

```
function check_URL() {
var url = "http://" + localStorage['t'] + ".somewhere.com";

$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(url)+
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if(data.results[0]){
        console.log("yes");
      } 
      else { 
      console.log("no");
      alert(url + " is not a valid URL or is down.");

     }
    }
  );

};
```

It does exactly what I want (and I found it here!). But, I need to check additional urls too.

How can I do that with an .each? I'm just too new to this stuff and an example will help my learning.

Also, if it helps, the domain "somewhere" used in the example will always be the same.

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Thiago who helped point me in the right direction.

```
function check_URL() {

var url = "http://" + localStorage['t'] + ".somewhere.com";
var url1 = "http://" + localStorage['t1'] + ".somewhere.com";
var url2 = "http://" + localStorage['t2'] + ".somewhere.com";
var url3 = "http://" + localStorage['t3'] + ".somewhere.com";

var urlArray = ['url', 'url1', 'url2','url3'];
$(urlArray).each(function (urlItem) {
$.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
            "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
            encodeURIComponent(urlItem)+
            "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if(data.results[0]){
        console.log("yes");
      } 
      else { 
      console.log("no");
      alert(url + " is not a valid URL or is down.");

     }
    }
  );
});
};
```

This seems to find any of the urls that don't validate but the alert is broken.

Ideas?

Thanks!

**FINAL UPDATE:** Working solution posted below.

Comment: so what have you tried so far?  You will learn so much faster if you try yourself first, then ask us if you get stuck.

Comment: @JonTaylor I've tried tearing my hair out but don't have much left. I don't ask questions here without spending at least a few hours of trying multiple approaches first and reading what I can. Sharing a bunch of failed attempts and clogging the site without a specific hitch is IMHO not useful. Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: I disagree, posting no attempted code is useless.  Posting a few failed attempts would not take up much room at all and people would be happy to help you out.

Comment: @JonTaylor Your wish may soon be granted.

Comment: @JonTaylor I updated above. Now there is a specific issue which is what you were looking for. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution I used. Thanks to @BaylorRae' for the guidance!

```
function check_URL() {

  var url = "http://" + localStorage['t'] + ".somewhere.com";
  var url1 = "http://" + localStorage['t1'] + ".somewhere.com";
  var url2 = "http://" + localStorage['t2'] + ".somewhere.com";
  var url3 = "http://" + localStorage['t3'] + ".somewhere.com";

  var urlArray = [url, url1, url2, url3],
      invalidUrls = [];

  $.each(urlArray, function (i, urlItem) {
    $.getJSON("http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?"+
    "q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22"+
    encodeURIComponent(urlItem)+
    "%22&format=xml'&callback=?",
    function(data){
      if(data.results[0]){
        console.log("yes");
      } 
      else { 
        invalidUrls.push(urlItem);
      }
    }
    );
  });

  return invalidUrls;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var urlArray = ['url', 'url1', 'url2'];
$(urlArray).each(function (urlItem) {
    //do your stuff with your urlItem string
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Thank you, we're close. I will post above. However, the alert fails and reports the value of the first "url" in the array rather than the url that has not validated.